# Optimizing declaring repeat variables?

Tags: c++

Is there anyway in which to avoid doing something like this:

```
std::queue<myStruct>  part1, part2, part3, part4, part5, part6, part7, part8, part9, part10;

void setup(){
myVector.push_back(part1);
myVector.push_back(part2);
myVector.push_back(part3);
myVector.push_back(part4);
myVector.push_back(part5);
myVector.push_back(part6);
myVector.push_back(part7);
myVector.push_back(part8);
myVector.push_back(part9);
myVector.push_back(part10);
}
```

Although this only goes up to part10 I may be going up towards 50 or more. Is it just a part of coding that somewhere it has to be declared or is there a dynamic way I can declare and assign these to the myVector these queues without writing it like this?

TIA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One easy way:

```
std::vector<std::queue<myStruct>> myVector(10);
```

Done!

Comment: @EricBanderhide, Note that the queues get default constructed as they are in your example.

Comment: I don't see how this does it? Am I being really short sighted? Where does it name the variables? Is the example just so brief as to be not quite helpful enough for a newbie like me?

Comment: @EricBanderhide, the queues can be accessed via `myVector [index]` or `myVector.at (index)` (the latter has out-of-bounds checking). Vectors are just like arrays, with some extra features and some more extra features to make them fit in.

Comment: Hang on I think you've lost me. So I get it in the vector then name them in a loop or something?

Comment: @EricBanderhide no, you don't name them, you access them by index. So the first one is `myVector[0]`, the second is `myVector[1]`, etc.

Comment: lol, yes I see what you both mean, I don't need to name them at all because I'm referencing them dynamically everywhere by their index in the vector. Unbelievably excellent simplification.  Vectors are the best thing since arrays aren't they? Its perfect thanks again for the input! I've learnt a lot this evening.

Comment: @Eric : In your code, you have named `queue`s, but they do **not** refer to the elements inside of the `vector` -- you're pushing _copies_ of your named variables into the `vector`.

Comment: @ildjarn, a very good point to remember if you're pushing in pre-used variables, and always good to learn the easy way.

Answer (score 0):

lets say your struct looks like this:

```
struct myStruct{

    //random variables that your struct may contain
    int num;
    std::string str;
    char ch;

    //Default Constructor
    //This allows your to create your structs without specifying any values;
    myStruct():
    num{999},str{"default"},ch{'z'}{}

    //Parameterized Constructor
    //This allows you to create your structs with specified values during initialization
    myStruct(int const numIn, std::string const& strIn, char const chIn):
    num{numIn},str{strIn},ch{chIn}{}

};
```

this will allow you to create instances the following way:

```
//calling default constructor
myStruct part1, part2, part3;

//calling parameterized constructor
myStruct part4{4,"4",'4'}, part5{5,"5",'5'}, part6{6,"6",'6'};
```

Now you want to put each one into a container and then put those containers into another container?

```
//this is a vector holding one deque holding 6 structs
vector<deque<myStruct>> vec{{part1,part2,part3,part4,part5,part6}};
+-------+
|  vec  |
|       |
|  [0]  |
+-------+
    |
   \'/
+-------+
|  deq  |
|       |-> part1
|  [0]  |
+-------+
|  deq  |
|       |-> part2
|  [1]  |
+-------+
|  deq  |
|       |-> part3
|  [2]  |
+-------+
|  deq  |
|       |-> part4
|  [3]  |
+-------+
|  deq  |
|       |-> part5
|  [4]  |
+-------+
|  deq  |
|       |-> part6
|  [5]  |
+-------+


//this is a vector holding 6 deques each holding 1 struct
vector<deque<myStruct>> vec2{{part1},{part2},{part3},{part4},{part5},{part6}};
+-------++-------++-------++-------++-------++-------+
|  vec  ||  vec  ||  vec  ||  vec  ||  vec  ||  vec  |
|       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       |
|  [0]  ||  [1]  ||  [2]  ||  [3]  ||  [4]  ||  [5]  |
+-------++-------++-------++-------++-------++-------+
    |        |        |        |        |        |
   \'/      \'/      \'/      \'/      \'/      \'/
+-------++-------++-------++-------++-------++-------+
|  deq  ||  deq  ||  deq  ||  deq  ||  deq  ||  deq  |
|       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||       |
|  [0]  ||  [0]  ||  [0]  ||  [0]  ||  [0]  ||  [0]  |
+-------++-------++-------++-------++-------++-------+
    |        |        |        |        |        |
   \'/      \'/      \'/      \'/      \'/      \'/
  part1    part2    part3    part4    part5    part6
```

We can do something even better though.  Let's initialize your structs while pushing them into a deque, while pushing the deque(s) into a vector.

```
//this is a vector holding one deque holding 6 structs
vector<deque<myStruct>> vec{{{1,"1",'1'},{2,"2",'2'},{3,"3",'3'},{4,"4",'4'},{5,"5",'5'},{6,"6",'6'}}};

//this is a vector holding 6 deques each holding 1 struct
vector<deque<myStruct>> vec2{{{1,"1",'1'}},{{2,"2",'2'}},{{3,"3",'3'}},{{4,"4",'4'}},{{5,"5",'5'}},{{6,"6",'6'}}};
```

keep in mind though, this is all C++11 initialization features.
I recommend you read this article to get accustomed.
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1852519

To compile code like this, make sure your compiler is up-to-date and you have the appropriate library files.
If your using gcc, compile with this flag:

> g++ -std=c++0x -o main main.cpp